# Changing Date Format from Google API

Tags: android, api, object, kotlin, formatting

I am currently trying to convert Google Calendars API DateTime to be in a standard (Month Day, Year Hours:Minutes format) but am still getting the original format 2018-06-26T10:30:00-05:00. Any suggestions on how to convert this? Ideally I would want to break it up into Month, Day, Year, Hours, Minutes.

```
if (events.length > 0) {
   for (i = 0; i < events.length; i++) {
      var event = events[i];
      var when = event.start.dateTime; 
      if (!when) { 
         when = event.start.date; 
      } 
      appendPre(event.summary + ' (' + startTime + ' to ' + endTime + ')') 
      console.log();
```

Comment: Could you post your code? What you tried to do?

Comment: I have tried parseInt and other methods similar to getDate();. But I suspect there is a similar way to break it down or I used those functions in the wrong spot.

Comment: 'if (events.length > 0) {
            for (i = 0; i < events.length; i++) {
              var event = events[i];
              var when = event.start.dateTime;
            
              if (!when) {
                when = event.start.date;
              }
              appendPre(event.summary + ' (' + startTime + ' to ' + endTime + ')')
              console.log();'

Comment: is it Kotlin? and you can add code in your post next time

Comment: I don't believe so. It is coming from the Google Calendars API. Seemingly the T in the middle of the date/time is messing things up. When I try things like getDate(); there are errors that pop up. Is there a way to break the string down by multiple parameters? I was able to break down the information but again the T is causing issues.